# Instantiate a prefab with a custom base object

Tags: unity-game-engine

Probably know the answer to this already but wanted to run this by the community anyways.

I have a custom object which contains the information I need to feed into a prefab.

I have read somewhere that messing around with contructors on prefabs is a bad idea. Is the best option then to simply pass the intitiatlization info via a method call on the prefab?

Ie: make a script for the prefab that accepts my custom object to configure it?  Kind of a best practices question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I would do it. Basically the prefab needs a reference (not necessarily a separate script) to another prefab with the extra data needed.

Though the question is: why can't this data be in the prefab itself?

If the answer is "because the data is global and there are many prefabs" a good solution to that problem is ScriptableObject, which acts as a global data storage object. A scriptable object has a script and an inspector view like other game objects, and you can assign a reference to the scriptable object to prefabs which can then reference the global data.

Typically ScriptableObject are used for "raw data" or even as a lightweight game database.

Script that creates a ScriptableObject (there are many examples):
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/CreateScriptableObjectAsset

This post explains the SO with a use case and code samples:
http://buchhofer.com/2010/10/unity-toying-with-scriptable-objects/

Comment: Thank you for this.  Still getting used to Unity's GUI environment.  They make it quite easy to do some interesting things.  Here's another example that I really liked:
http://www.jacobpennock.com/Blog/?p=670

Comment: Just coming back to this, despite high hopes for Scriptable Objects as my datasource, I switched to SQLite.  SO doesn't serialize polymorphism, which is a requirement.  :(